# What's new in .net 4 for MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, frameworks, .net-4.0

Does .net 4 add anything new for working with MVVM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much... however, there has been one useful addition : `InputBinding.Command` and `InputBinding.CommandParameter` are now bindable dependency properties, which makes it much easier to handle keyboard and mouse events

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight 4.0, although not .NET 4.0, we now have the ICommand on Buttonbase which allows for easier binding of commands to buttons.

Answer (score -4):

No.

Some say that WPF was built with MVVM in mind, so the needed features were there from the start.

Comment: Who says that ? I think MVVM was built to take advantage of WPF, not the other way around... but I might be wrong of course ;)

Comment: MVVM is a name and suggested practices for taking advantage of WPF in the way it was meant for.

Comment: MVVM was introduced in 2005, during the development of WPF. http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx